# Angular 6 Bootstrap Carousel Routing back Problem

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

i have a problem on Angular 6 with Bootstrap 4 Carousel.
It's working when starting just fine. My problem comes in addition with routing.

On Page A i have my carousel.

```
<div id="homebanner-carousel" class="carousel slide " data-pause="false"
       data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#homebanner-carousel"
          *ngFor="let item of homeBannerInformation; let i = index"
          [attr.data-slide-to]="i" [class.active]="i == 0"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let item of homeBannerInformation; let i = index"
           [class.active]="i == 0">
        <img class="d-block mx-auto" src="{{item.imageUrl}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then i route to Page B. Now, when i route back to Page A (either by angular routing or with browser back button) the carousel shows just fine but doesnt autoplay anymore.

Except for an OnInit Method my TS-File is blank.

Any idea where i can look into?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone faceing a similar issue.
You have to restart the carousel with the method carousel().

Therefore in the TS-File

```
//imports jquery    
declare var $: any;

.....
ngOnInit() {
   .....
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.carousel').carousel();
   })
}
```